# С помощью вложенных циклов выведите на экран все строки с данными

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

```
let data = [
    {
        1: 'data11',
        2: 'data12',
        3: 'data13',
    },
    {
        1: 'data21',
        2: 'data22',
        3: 'data33',
    },
    {
        1: 'data31',
        2: 'data32',
        3: 'data33',
    },
];

for (let elem of data) {
    for (let res in data[elem]) {
        console.log(res)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пару ошибок:

- `elem` уже является конкретным элементом на данной итерации цикла, поэтому не нужно обращаться к элементу как `data[elem]`
- `res` -- текущий ключ объекта. Чтобы получить значение свойства объекта, нужно обратиться как `elem[res]`

Информация по циклам:

- [Цикл for-in](https://learn.javascript.ru/object#forin)
- [Цикл for-of](https://learn.javascript.ru/array#loops)

Итоговый вариант:

```js
let data = [
    {
        1: 'data11',
        2: 'data12',
        3: 'data13',
    },
    {
        1: 'data21',
        2: 'data22',
        3: 'data33',
    },
    {
        1: 'data31',
        2: 'data32',
        3: 'data33',
    },
];

for (let elem of data) {
    for (let res in elem) {
        console.log(elem[res]);
    }
}
```